# mysql join two ids with one description table

Tags: mysql, join

My problem is that I have this table `status`:

```
  Id | Cie_1 | Cie_2
  -------------------
  1  | 'A460'| 'J960'

  2  | 'K830'| 'R571'
```

and this table `cie`

```
  IdCie | Dec

  'J960'| DecJ960

  'A460 | DecA460

  'K830'| DecK830

  'R571'| DecR571
```

Now I want to select with the column `dec` like this

```
 Id  | Cie_1 |  dec_1  | Cie_2 | dec_2
  ---------------------------------
  1  | 'A460'| DecA460 | 'J960'| DecJ960

  2  | 'K830'| DecK830 | 'R571'| DecR571
```

I try to use this but have the unknown column error for `a.idCie`

```
select a.idCie as cie_1, c.dec as dec_1,b.idCie as cie_2, d.dec as dec_2
  from cie a,cie b 
  join cie c on c.idCie=a.idCie
  join cie d on d.idCie=b.idCie;
```

update:

> select a.Cie_1 , c.dec as dec_1,b.Cie_2, d.dec as dec_2
>         from status a,status b 
>         join cie c on c.idCie=a.Cie_1
>         join cie d on d.idCie=b.Cie_2;

but i hava a unknow column error on a.Cie_1

update:

thanks one last question

Status

```
Id | Cie_1 | Cie_2 

1  | 'A460'| null
```

the result doesnt show neither Cie_1

```
 Id  | Cie_1 |  dec_1  | Cie_2 | dec_2
  -------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This joins them

```
select status.id, status.cie_1, cie1.dec as dec_1, status.cie_2, cie2.dec as dec_2
from status join cie as cie1 on status.cie_1 = cie1.idcie
join cie as cie2 on status.cie_2 = cie2.idcie
```

Taking your table structure you want to link `Cie_1` from the `status` table to the `cie` table `idcie`.  That is you want to *lookup* A460 (and get the value DecA460) from cie based on `idcie`.  This is represented by the first join `join cie as cie1 on status.cie_1 = cei1.idcie`.  See the table representation below.  Then just do it again for `Cie_2`

---

```
Status                     cie
Id | Cie_1 | Cie_2         IdCie | Dec
1  | 'A460'| 'J960'  -->   A460  | DecA460
```

---

You can see the results below...

[image: results]

Comment: the table has more rows duplicates like this

Comment: Id  | Cie_1 |  dec_1  | Cie_2 | dec_2
  ---------------------------------
  1  | 'A460'| DecA460 | 'A460'| DecA460

  2  | 'K830'| DecK830 | 'K830'| DecK830

Comment: I'll update my answer to add the `Distinct` keyword.  I think that should help... unless... Are you talking about duplicate columns?  If you do select * you will see columns for all three tables, status, cie1 and cie2 which will have duplicate values based on the join.  That's why I selected only specific columns.

Comment: @user2876735 I just tested this and it does exactly what you want. I had a typo where I had cei instead of cie.  Other than that it should be good.

Comment: @user2876735 Then you didn't use my query.  I don't have `a.Cie_1` in it.  I did just update a typo as I said in the last comment.  Use my query and if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: thanks in the final join i use a left join and i think that this solve the final problem